Bazel Build with VxWorks Environment (wrenv.exe)
What is the cleanest way to configure a build environment using wrenv.exe when running a bazel build command.
bazel build --platforms=@my_bazel//platforms::vxworks_69_arm7 //crypto:crypto 

I would like to override the tool_path, but have not had success.
tool_path(
    name = "gcc",
    path = "c:/path/to/wrenv.exe -p vxworks-6.9 ccarm",
)

Setting up a genrule as follows seems like a hack?
genrule(
    name = "setup_and_build_crypto_7.0",
    srcs = [],
    outs = ["build_output_env1.txt"],
    cmd = """
        C:/path/to/wrenv.exe -p vxworks-7.0 && \
        bazel build //crypto:crypto > $@
    """,
)

genrule(
    name = "setup_and_build_crypto_6.9",
    srcs = [],
    outs = ["build_output_env2.txt"],
    cmd = """
        C:/path/to/wrenv.exe -p vxworks-6.9 && \
        bazel build //crypto:crypto > $@
    """,
)

Any ideas?

I ended up just creating a feature with the environment variables that wrenv.exe creates and attaching that to my tooolchain.



